# Adding a parameterized parameter to a jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I need to add a same boolean parameter ( from "Add Parameter" drop-down menu) to 100 existing jobs.
What is a better way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for Jenkins job-dsl https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin

This exposes the job structure to an API which can be used to modify the configuration. This is run as a separate Jenkins build step in a job

Answer (score 0):

There is also a somewhat unwieldy, yet oftentimes-handy, plugin called [Configuration Slicing](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin). I've found it useful sometimes, in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Build Flow** plugin. It allows to write DSL scripts.

example:

```
build("job-name", parameter:"vlaue1")

build("job-name", parameter:"vlaue2")
```

you can pass as many values like this.